# What is the best way to handle conversation states in Facebook Messenger bot?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I've been reading through several Messenger bot tutorials and they all stop at the same phase: reply to a user input with a single message. Although this is useful, I want to build a bot that changes responses based on which state of the conversation it is at. What is the best way to handle each conversation state?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want your bot to be intelligent but just follow a flow of messages depending on user's reply, you can store different states of your flow in db or locally. Then via use of strings like 10100 means he said yes to first query and then no then yes and so on, you can serve him the the payload you want. A switch could be used for such cases.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should use any kind of AI algorithm that detects certain kind of keywords, the keyword could be stored in a relational DB, for example if the person tell "ciao" or "bye" or "good bye" or "sayonara" or "see u" then the bot can recognaise this as the end of the conversation and give a answer according to that.

Comment: that's exactly what he said he doesn't want to do

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not quite what I'm looking for. I was thinking I should make a good use of payloads or something